# pdo sqlite could not find driver... php file not processing

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Hi i'm received the **could not find driver** error when trying to connect to sqlite via a php file. I've set permission to 777... PHP Version 5.2.16, i have the module install. any reason why its not finding the driver, also php.ini is showing the extension pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so installed.

**PDO**

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql

**pdo_mysql**

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version    5.0.92

```
try {
    // Connect to the SQLite Database.
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:.subscribers.db');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('connection_unsuccessful: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)

Comment: On Windows, the only thing that helped me was to add "C:\Program Files\php" to the system PATH environment variables, although I cannot imagine why.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need

```
[PDO_SQLITE]
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

to be enabled, for `sqlite:.subscribers.db`

or, for Windows:

```
[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

And of course this extension in your `ext` directory.

Comment: do i have to recompile php to get the pdo_sqlite.so extension?

Comment: no, just add `*.so` file to `ext` dir, add few lines in `php.ini` and that's all

Comment: ok i figured it out `sudo pecl install pdo_sqlite` did the trick i did pdo_mysql earlier sqlite did the trick.

Comment: Also, on ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822209/pdo-sqlite-driver-not-present-what-to-do

Comment: I have edited /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini then i have restarted Apache (sudo service apache2 restart)

Answer (score 39):

I had to actually install the extension, and this is how i did on **Ubuntu 16** running **PHP 7.1**:

`sudo apt install php7.1-sqlite3`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` for php5 on Ubuntu server 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: or `sudo apt install php-sqlite3` for all variations of php7

Comment: `sudo apt install php8.0-sqlite3` if you use PHP 8.

Answer (score 11):

On archlinux i had to do two things:

first install [php-sqlite](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/php-sqlite/)

```
pacman -S php-sqlite
```

after that in my `php.ini` file for me in `/etc/php/php.ini` i had to uncomment this line:

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

by removing semicolon.

Dont forget to restart server.

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Thx. I just uncomment ;extension=pdo_sqlite.so as you said.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a portable version of PHP on windows, using the inbuilt web server. I found the following steps helped:

1. Renaming php.ini-development to php.ini
2. Uncommenting `extension_dir = "ext"` under [PHP] (around line 700)
3. making sure the following lines are in the php.ini:

```
[sqlite3]    
sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"    
extension = sqlite3    
extension = pdo_sqlite
```

4. Running the php webserver with the following flag added on: `- c C:\Path\to\PortablePHP\php.ini`

So currently my php command is `php -S localhost:8081 -c B:\Downloads\php-7.2.6\php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

[**Debian 11 (bullseye)** provides `php7.4-sqlite3`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/php7.4-sqlite3):

```
apt install php7.4-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite3
worked for me