# PDO_SQLITE driver not present.. what to do?

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony, php-extension

I see everywhere (including on the official docs) that the **PDO_SQLITE** driver is/should be included by default in PHP.

However, when I look at my `extension_directory`, I see only these files:

`gd.so  mcrypt.so  mysqli.so  mysql.so  pdo_mysql.so  pdo.so`

And, as a result, a framework I'm trying to install (Symfony) tells me I need to install either the PDO_SQLITE or the SQLite3 .so extensions...

Can anyone help? Can I just try and find the needed .so file somewhere on the web, place it in my extensions_directory and then include it in **php.ini**??

**BTW:** I'm running php 5.3.6 downloaded via apt-get on ubuntu.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

did you try `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite`?

Current version:
`sudo apt install php7.4-sqlite`

Comment: I never cease to be amazed at just how simple linux is... Thanks for that.. Silly of me not to have thought of that first thing off. However. Shouldn't this SQLITE thing be available as default?

Comment: you're welcome! according to the docs it should be. but in my fedora install i had to install it by hand, though it was strange because it was enabled in php.ini, but like you said the driver was not present anywhere...

Comment: The sqlite module is availalbe after a PHP build from sources. But Linux distros often do their own thing. Most every module is available in their repositories - and most need to be explicitly installed.

Comment: And for PHP7, you need to run: ``sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3``

Comment: Thanks worked fine for me with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 :-)

Comment: **And for PHP 7.1**, you need to run: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3`

Comment: **And of PHP 7.2**:
`sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`

Comment: I think the above specifies the php 5 version, you will need to do something like this for the other greater php versions e.g. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`

Comment: Similarly for PHP 7.3 use sudo apt-get install php7.3-sqlite3

Comment: for me `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3` works fine with php 7.2

Comment: `php-sqlite3` should automatically update with `php`.

Comment: E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-sqlite3'

Comment: Just so you know, `php5-sqlite` has been deleted from Ubunutu repositories.

Answer (score 34):

**For PHP 7.0 and greater:**

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Comment: Or sudo apt-get install php7.X-sqlite  , where X is the correponding number of of your fpm

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-sqlite3

Comment: It's ok to add you php version but you still need to add the 3 after sqlite

Answer (score 8):

For Windows users:

removed comment (`;`) from php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case i was using php 7.2 in Ubuntu. I had to run following command,

```
sudo apt install php7.2-sqlite
```

Comment: E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-sqlite'

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 - 64bits, version PHP 7.2
It's necessary remove only ( ; ) 
Before
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=sqlite3

After
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3

Restart the server and already.

Comment: Not universally.  7.3.9 works; 7.4.14 not so much.  Same for the Rajput (above) 'solution.'

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 8.1.2

sudo apt install php8.1-sqlite3

Comment: Thanks! And unsurprisingly, for php 8.2 it's `apt install php8.2-sqlite3` :)