# Symfony 4 : ADD SQLITE DATABASE

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have a problem with symfony to replace the mysql database with sqlite, and so actually I've already done some research on the subject and so I've already done some things like :

- [change the database in the .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sOeY.png)

  - [change the drivers to use (pdo_sqlite) in the doctrine file in App/config/packages/doctrine.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7muw.png)
  - [clean the cache and try to create the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0IXx.png)

but I keep running into these red error lines

Comment: Could you edit your question and add "these red erroneous lines written in red" :)

Comment: Well, it's done... and also you have an idea how to solve the problem ?

Comment: I still don't see the "red errors lines". what @qdequippe asked you is to edit your post with these errors. without them we cannot magically know what's going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally, the solution was quite simple it was enough to install the appropriate driver for the good version of php I work with php7.3 so it was necessary to do:

sudo apt-get install sqlite3

sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser

sudo apt-get install php7.3-sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the recommendations from the official Symfony [documentation for doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine.html)?

The .env file should be like this:

`DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/app.db"`

Also this should help you:

[PDO_SQLITE driver not present.. what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822209/pdo-sqlite-driver-not-present-what-to-do)

Comment: Yes I did this .. and thanks  a lot for your attention .. but the problem came from the sqlite extensions that were not installed on the PC.